# How would I make an if statement for if a UILabel says a particular phrase?

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4.2, uialertview, ios5

I have some code here but it's not working. What I want is to check when the UILabel shows something, example:

```
    if(label.text=@"3"{
NSLog(@"Label showing three");
}
```

Any help appreciated,

Seb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way a label can have a "3" (or any text) is if your program puts it there somehow. You should never need to test the contents of a label -- test for the condition that would lead to the label having the value you're interested in. More generally, a well designed program uses views to display the state of the program, it doesn't store the state of the program in its views.

If you're really bent on testing a label, though, every label has a `text` property that will give you its value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is it possible to do something like: if the text shows a three that a UIAlertView with show? Thanks.

Comment: @user826671 Yes, it's possible. NSString's methods make it simple to compare two strings, and you can of course do whatever you like based on the result. But when would you perform this check? A UILabel doesn't change its value by itself -- you have to set it. So why not do the check then, before you've even set the label?